# Make openbox automatically start to use a specific gtk profile

Tags: linux, gnome, window-manager, gtk, openbox

all. I have switched to openbox from Gnome and would now like to stop using Metacity altogether. When I was using metacity I had both a control theme (e.g. gtk theme) and fonts set up how I liked them in gnome-appearance-proporties. When Openbox starts, it gets my window borders up properly (ofc.) but fails to render my fonts properly and uses the wrong gtk theme. I can't find anywhere to specify which gtk theme to use or what method to render my text with. After Openbox is finished doing it's thing, and I run gnome-apperance-properties manually, it will automatically set everything to it's proper value, but I don't want to have to do this as it takes several seconds to preform and I'd rather not have it jury rigged like this.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you want ~/.gtk2rc, or something similar. I forget what file specifically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/usr/libexec/gnome-settings-daemon` manages all of this. I run it at startup now to avoid having to deal with the ~/.gtkrc-2.0 and font configs.

Answer (score 1):

Gtk theme, icon and font settings can be specified in the file:

```
$HOME/.gtkrc-2.0
```

If you don't want to manually edit this file, try [`lxappearance`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=738747).